# How to write basic authentication in AngularJS to show JSON data coming from API in table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, api

I have one rest API which has basic authentication with user-id and password (123:123), while I'm running code showing unauthorized in js console. how to add basic authentication in function so that it can be authorized like this code

```
 headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa("xxx:yyy")},
```

my code

```
   <body>

        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">

            <table>
                <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
                    <td>{{ x.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ x.city }}</td>

                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>

        <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

        $http.get("https://example.com/name/data/1")

        .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.records;});
    });
        </script>

    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could Set the default Authorization Header once the user login. And clean it, when the user logout.

```
       $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + login + ':' +    password);
```

And you could define a Factory Service to manage the login status, with a few methods.

```
.factory('AuthenticationService', function($q, $http) {

    var loggedIn = false;

    var service = {
        login: function(credentials) {

            var def = $q.defer();
            $http.post('loginURL')

            .then(
                function(response) {
                    $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = response.header;
                    loggedIn = true;
                },
                function(response) {
                    return def.reject(response);
                }
            );
            return def.promise
        },

        isLoggedIn: function() {
            return loggedIn;
        },

        logout: function() {
            loggedIn = false;
            delete $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization;
        }
    };

    return service;
})
```

For instance, in your controller you could use AuthenticationService.isLoggedIn() to check is the user is logged.

Comment: should i write all these in script. can u tell me more about how to write this code

Comment: actually did u understand what i want . i have api which has basic authentication. need code to show data in div.

Answer (score 0):

Use Interceptor,This will act a gateway to  all your request and response.
so you can add all your headers in all the request.
Check this http://onehungrymind.com/winning-http-interceptors-angularjs/